# ASP.NET Splitting string into an array not working from objective-c?

Tags: c#, asp.net, objective-c, arrays

I have a string like so:

`~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY & INSTALL - 25% of CONTRACT*~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY & INSTALL - 75% of CONTRACT*SUMP PUMP PIT`

and this is coming from this:

```
string Items = Request.QueryString["Items"];
```

and then I take this string and split by the `*` character:

```
var ItemsArray = Items.Split('*');
```

but ItemsArray only returns:

```
~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY
```

Here is something interesting, string Items returns: ~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY also:

Here is what Items looks like in the URL:

```
Items=~SEWER/FLATWORK%20SUPPLY%20&%20INSTALL%20-%2025%25%20of%20CONTRACT*~SEWER/FLATWORK%20SUPPLY%20&%20INSTALL%20-%2075%25%20of%20CONTRACT*SUMP%20PUMP%20PIT
```

I am creating this item in objective-c like so:

```
[Items appendString:[object objectForKey:@"Items"]];
[Items appendString:@"*"];
[Items deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([Items length]-1, 1)];
//This returns this: ~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY & INSTALL - 25% of CONTRACT*~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY & INSTALL - 75% of CONTRACT*SUMP PUMP PIT

//add Items to URL
NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://example.com?Items=%@, [Items stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I am expecting the array to return like so:

```
~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY & INSTALL - 25% of CONTRACT
~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY & INSTALL - 75% of CONTRACT
SUMP PUMP PIT
```

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: Problem is that `space&space` is `%20&%20` but should be `%20%26%20 ` to prevent parsing as a query string param

Comment: how would I do that @AlexK.

Comment: You would change the url encoding such that it encodes `&` in your obj-c code, I don't know that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to remove HTTP Encoding and after that you can split your string. Try the following method. 
You need to add two namespaces: System.Web & System.Text.RegularExpressions

```
string Items = Request.QueryString["Items"];
Items = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Items);
string[] ItemsArray = Regex.Split(Items, "*");
```

Hope this help you...